# C++: Does vector of pointer elements automatically deallocate dynamic memory pointed by each pointer upon destruction?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

The title is self explanatory - does the standard vector implementation take care of deallocating dynamic memory pointed to by all the pointers that are in the vector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. When you destroy a `std::vector` it destroys all its elements (calls their destructor) and then deallocates the storage used by the objects. But a (raw) pointer does not have a destructor - destroying it does *not* deallocate the object it points to - it just destroys the storage used to hold the pointer itself.

If you had had a `vector` of smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) then it would be a different matter. Those classes *do* have destructors and *do* deallocate what they point to upon destruction (`unique_ptr` always, `shared_ptr` if it's the last object pointing to the contained object, otherwise it just decrements its reference count).

Note: a `std::unique_ptr` is a *very thin* wrapper around a raw pointer, that is designed to optimize away completely. So, using it should have zero overhead over a raw pointer when optimization is enabled. So it'll give you the semantics you want with *no overhead* compared to doing the manual memory management - manually.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't.

If you want "self-deleting" pointers use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) or (depending on what the pointers are used for) a container such as `std::vector`, `std::array` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. Containers are not reponsible of the memory management of raw pointers. It would be possible to automatically deallocate your pointer elements if they were smart pointers (RAII : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)

You can see a pointer as a simple integer. Its value represents a memory address. When the vector pointer element is deleted, the bytes allocated to store this address are freed. Thus, the memory address pointed by the pointer is lost (No more reference to it = memory leak).

Containers will never manipulate your instances (Free pointers, modify content). It can only call constructors (Specified one, copy, move...) and the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the what pointers the `vector` is containing, for raw pointers like

```
std::vector<Something*>
```

no, you have to do the cleanup yourself.

If the `vector` contains smart pointers, on the other hand, like `std::unique_ptr`

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Something>>
```

then the cleanup is taken care of for you.

Long story short: try to use smart pointers.